# Creating a maze in Python/Pygame but not sure how to make walls

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

windowwidth = 600
windowheight = 800
WALLWIDTH = 30
WALLHEIGHT = 30
PLAYERWIDTH = 20
PLAYERHEIGHT = 20


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
LIMEGREEN = (50, 205, 50)

running = True
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w):
            elif (event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s):
            elif (event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a):
            elif (event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d):

thescreen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowwidth, windowheight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Maze Game')
mainclock = pygame.time.Clock()

player1 = pygame.draw.rect(thescreen, LIMEGREEN, (50, 50, PLAYERWIDTH, PLAYERHEIGHT))
```

I am trying to create a maze game (not generator) for a project in school using Python/Pygame. I have looked all over for a way to create walls and make a player (just a green rect) collide with these walls, and how to make several levels for this. How would I make levels, how would I create walls, and how would I detect collision between player and walls?

Comment: First result after googleing http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=maze_runner.py

Comment: What have you tried? Could you add the code you currently have? Without looking at your specific code, there's really no way for anybody to easily help you besides explaining some very basic, general, principles. (Click the "edit" button in the bottom left to update your question).

Comment: I haven't done much code at the moment, but I can! I'm just not sure.

Comment: I suggest you read the docs and try to be more specific so it is easier for people here to point you in the right direction. The way it is your question is to broad...

Comment: For how to draw walls: well, you know how to draw a player, so do something similar to that. You can draw a line, a square, whatever. For how to determine if the player and the wall collide, Google for "collision detection", or if that appears to gory, "pygame collision detection". For how to make multiple levels: try making one level first.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for it being really broad, I just wasn't sure where to start with making it. I'm just really new to programming and wasn't sure how to best ask this question.. I know you can make a list for the walls and append them to the list, or make a txt file containing what you want as walls etc. Thanks for trying to point in the right direction anyway :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the two easiest ways I know of making walls. Both ways work with graph structures and graph search algorithms so you can implement "path-finding" in the future if you wish. This is all off the top of my head so I apologize if any of it is unclear, but I have also provided links to relevant pieces of documentation that you can check out if you are confused.

## Method 1: Tile-Based Maze

This is probably the easiest method to generate maps in because it can by done simply by making an array of ASCII characters and processing them in Python to make square "wall" objects.

Take this grid for example:

```
###########
#         #
#  ###### #
#S #F     #
###########
```

'S' denotes the starting point and 'F' denotes the finish point. Yes this is probably the easiest "maze" to solve in the world but it's just an example. Imagine that each character in my horrible ASCII array represents a square tile of size N x N. The spaces represent the characters the tile can walk on and the hash characters represent walls '#'.

In this type of game, walls are game entities themselves. Specifically in the context of Pygame, they inherit from the [Sprite class](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html). Sprite classes are special classes which represent entities, or basically existing objects in your game. They are very special because they can represent obstacles, walls, floors, ceilings, players, enemies, you name it. Basically every object in your game can inherit from the Sprite class.

So what makes Sprite classes so special? Well for one, you mentioned that you were having conceptual difficulty understanding wall-collision. Each sprite in Pygame has its own [Rect attribute](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). A rect attribute is basically just an invisible rectangle that is used to determine things like collision detection, and drawing sprites. By definition, in a pure tile-based map, a "collision" between entities is defined as follows: Two entities are colliding if their rectangles overlap each other. Then there is a method of the Sprite class called [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect). Each wall in the ASCII map above has a width, height, and location determined by their position in the array. Thus each hashtag character directly represents a rectangle that is also a square and has a square "surface" image.

Have your player inherit from the sprite class and place him in one sprite group, the "player group". Have your wall entities inherit from the sprite class and place them in another sprite group, call this the "obstacle group" or something similar.  All you have to do then is call [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect) in every frame of your game loop and use the dictionary it returns to tell if the player is colliding with any sprites. I've provided links to the documentation if any of this is unclear. Reading the Pygame documentation will probably help you understand this better than my answer can.

So anyways what you end up with in the end of all this is a *dictionary*. I'll make a direct quote from the documentation to explain my point:

```
groupcollide(group1, group2, dokill1, dokill2, collided = None) -> Sprite_dict
This will find collisions between all the Sprites in two groups. Collision is
determined by comparing the Sprite.rect attribute of each Sprite or by using the 
collided function if it is not None.

Every Sprite inside group1 is added to the return dictionary. The value 
for each item is the list of Sprites in group2 that intersect.
```

You would call this function directly in every iteration of your game loop *after* you update the player's movement and *before* you draw all your entities using the player's group as the `group1` argument, and the obstacles group as your `group2` argument. Then you end up with a dictionary of the following form:

```
{player_in_group1: [<list of obstacles from group2 that collide with player>] }
```

So what do you do with that list? Well its recommended that you define your own local function (you can also make it a method of player class if you wish) for dealing with this. Here is my extremely high-level pseudo code implementation which is not close to actual code at all:

```
def handle_collisions(sprite_dict):
    '''given sprite dict, moves all entities in group1 out of group2's
       rectangle area'''
    for p in sprite_dict:
        for o in sprite_dict[p]:
            # move p in such a way that its rectangle is no longer overlapping
            # with the rectangle of o with the additional constraint that p must
            # be moved **as minimally as possible.**
```

I'm not going to implement the function for you since I feel it would be better to leave the challenge to you. :) I will warn you that the logic is not that simple, however.

Incidentally this type of maze/map structure is used in many popular games including Legend of Zelda, Pacman, Bomberman, Tetris, etc, etc. I couldn't possibly name them all but you get the point. This is a *proven* method since it seamlessly integrates itself with game design. But don't take my word for it, there is [an entire website which explains why tile-based games are so powerful.](http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/tut00.html)

## Method 2: Vertex-Edge Based Maze

Note this method is much harder to implement. It's purely [Graph based.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) Each space in the graph is a node which the player can traverse. What determines whether an entity is allowed to move between two nodes (in other words...collision based on the principle of *restriction*) is whether or not an *edge* exists between those two nodes in the underlying undirected (or directed, if you wish) graph.

I'm not really going to explain this in detail because it's just too difficult to cover in one answer. You'll just have to do your own research if you want to use this method but keep in mind it's a lot harder since Pygame doesn't actually support you much for this strategy. If you're really interested in this, the best place to start is probably [Google](http://google.com).

---

And that's it! Make an attempt with the information I've given you and if you have any trouble with this, you can ask another question here or on [The GameDev StackExchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). In the future when you ask a question on SO, try and make sure that it is a *specific programming question* or you will very likely get lots of downvotes.

Comment: Thankyou ever so much, I'm just really new to programming in Pygame and have tried to get information like this, but can't find it anywhere and I wasn't sure on how to word it, so I'm sorry if it seemed really broad! Thankyou again!

Comment: @user2816999 No problem. :) You can accept my answer if you found it helpful. You can do that by clicking on the green checkmark to the upper left of my answer.

Comment: Thankyou again. :D I have done! Sorry if it seemed broad, I just wasn't sure the best way of asking it.. And I know you can make walls in lists inside the coding, and as a txt file but I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: @user2816999 Walls are just class instances. Do you know a bit about Python classes?

Comment: No I don't.. I'm teaching myself how to program in Python, so my skills are very bad.

Comment: @user2816999 Don't worry about it. Just spend a bit of time reading through the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). I taught myself Python too. :) It's not that hard if you just do some reading.

Comment: Yeah! I should do really.. Thankyou! Nice :) it makes me wonder how you get so good at it! Well I'm just worrying a bit, skipping out on a lot of things because this project has to be in by next March.. :(

Comment: @user2816999 Next March? Plenty of time! You'll be fine. ^_^

Comment: Hope so! Haha! Do you know how you could make seperate levels? Would I use define function for each level?

Comment: @user2816999 Well there's lots of different ways to store levels. For example you could just use a dictionary of dictionaries or a class or just a function...Seriously read more of the Python tutorial. :P Game programming is no joke. There are lots of ways to do things and half the challenge (and fun) is thinking up of *your* own way.

Comment: Yeah.. :P you can tell how good I am! I'm just stuck sometimes because I see people do things one way and I'm not sure how to do it another way.. Anyway, that's going besides the point. You're right, it is! Thankyou for your help, it's really appreciated!

Comment: @user2816999: One thing to add about this nice design is that it allows you to build and test the PyGame and "logic" parts of your program separately, and to debug by log messages, and to create levels without having to write a complicated level editor, and so on. A 2D array of ASCII characters (aka a "text file") is the easiest thing in the world to deal with, and Shashank's answer allows you to build your whole program around that easiest thing in the world.